# Github action/workflow failed to publish to NPM

Tags: github-actions

This is my git workflow code :

```
# NPM Publish is the name for this action
name: NPM Publish

# This action will trigger on every release get created
on:
  release:
    types: [created]

# Job will run on a ubuntu instance
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: "16.X"
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/          
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm test
      - run: npm ci
      # publish the files to NPM
      - run: npm publish --access public
      # for publishing, npm need authorization. We add the NPM token to the environment which will take care of authorization to publish to the package
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_SECRET}}
```

I've added a action/workflow into it so I can make releases of my changes to NPM (AUTOMATION).

I've searched a lot but I'm stuck at publish command. Even I've added secrets into repo keys/variables too.

[image]

I've searched a lot of stackover solution to solve this problem, And I applied everything, but still I'm not able to solve this problem.

I've tried npm login, npm publish ( without access public ) command. Still no helps!

I need help where I'm doing wrong so I can make it automated. Each time I try/make changes, It stuck at the same place i.e.

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/react-lightbox-js - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'react-lightbox-js@1.2.1' is not in this registry.
```

Although I've checked the same url in browser and it returns the data ( GET) request. But it fails with the automation ( PUT) request.

I need help to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see your code file. There could be a possible cases which mention below :

```
 env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_SECRET}}
```

Here you are setting env.
**NODE_AUTH_TOKEN**: this is going to be set into your CI/CD env in GitHub action.
so make sure that in your file :

.npmrc contains the following code :

if your file has this code :

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_SECRET}
```

Here is the issue, Possible solution for this could be :

**Either update this file with this code**

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NODE_AUTH_TOKEN}
```

**OR**

update your workflow code of env with this code:

```
env:
          NPM_SECRET: ${{secrets.NPM_SECRET}}
```

Both are equivalent.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, It worked, Issue was with the env key.